# iOS 14.2+ MaterialComponents password field displays blank keyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, material-components-ios

I'm using `pod 'MaterialComponents/TextControls+OutlinedTextFields'`.
For non-password text fields, keyboard normally shows when I tap on the text field.

But for the password fields it's different, when I tap first, it shows completely grey keyboard, when I tap onto another field and tap back to password, it displays strong password recommendation (it should do it on first tap).

I tried to update pods but error still appearing.

[image]

Comment: can you share your codes please ? it is difficult to figure out the problem like this

Comment: there is no code other than decleration, I just put the label into nib file.
    @IBOutlet var passwordTextField: MDCOutlinedTextField!

Comment: there is no code. ok